# Trying to calculate age in C

Tags: c

Can you tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int CurrentYear;
    int BornYear;
    int age = CurrentYear - BornYear;

    printf("What year is it?\n");
    scanf("%d", &CurrentYear);
    //printf("Year check: %d\n", CurrentYear);
    printf("What year you were born?\n");
    scanf("%d", &BornYear);
    //printf("Year check: %d\n", BornYear);
    printf("You are %d years old\n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting some wierd numbers as result.

Comment: Run the code in a debugger and see what happens. C is a procedural language which means everything happens in order. Think what is done in which order in your code. And then warnings to max to get useful hints about problems.

Comment: Move the line computing `age` after you set current year and born year

Comment: Quick note: calculate the **age** variable after taking the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressions in C are not formulas.  This:

```
int age = CurrentYear - BornYear;
```

Does not mean that the value of `age` will *always* be `CurrentYear - BornYear`.  It means that *at that point in the code*, `age` is set to `CurrentYear - BornYear` based on the current value of those variables.  Both of those variables are uninitialized, so their values are indeterminate.

You need to move the calculation of `age` to **after** you've read in `CurrentYear` and `BornYear`:

```
int CurrentYear;
int BornYear;
int age;

printf("What year is it?\n");
scanf("%d", &CurrentYear);
printf("What year you were born?\n");
scanf("%d", &BornYear);

age = CurrentYear - BornYear;
printf("You are %d years old\n", age);
```

Comment: That's a very nice explanation. +1

Comment: Thank your help.
Now it is perfectly clear what went wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Madnevil and Welcome to StackOverflow;

You are getting a wrong result because the order of the instructions of your program is wrong, you are calculating the age before reading `CurrentYear` and `BornYear`:

The right way to do this is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    int CurrentYear = 0;
    int BornYear = 0;


    printf("What year is it?\n");
    scanf("%d", &CurrentYear);
    //printf("Year check: %d\n", CurrentYear);
    printf("What year you were born?\n");
    scanf("%d", &BornYear);
    //printf("Year check: %d\n", BornYear);

    int age = CurrentYear - BornYear;

    printf("You are %d years old\n", age);
        return 0; 
}
```

also you may ask so why the result is not 0, because you haven't yet initialized the variables?

the answer is that i C programming language things are differents it takes a random variables from Memory. So as a good practice always initialize your variable